# How can I access Sails.js routes from EJS?

Tags: node.js, routes, sails.js, ejs

I would like to link to my Sails.js routes from `<a>` elements.

It should have a similar effect as (for instance) [ui-sref for AngularJS](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.directive:ui-sref), but for my EJS pages which are rendered by the server and are static on the client.